# Storybook does not start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I have created react app with and `create-react-app` (and not made any changes in the app ) and initialized storybook by running `npx sb init` but running `yarn storybook` gives the following error. I have also tried this with nextjs but  storybook gives the same error.

```
    ERR! SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /%G++%/: Nothing to repeat
    ERR!     at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    ERR!     at H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-common\dist\cjs\utils\template.js:20:24
    ERR!     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    ERR!     at interpolate (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-common\dist\cjs\utils\template.js:19:31)
    ERR!     at getManagerHeadTemplate (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-common\dist\cjs\utils\template.js:63:10)
    ERR!     at _default (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\manager\manager-webpack.config.js:61:99)
    ERR!     at async Object.start (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\manager\builder.js:94:16)
    ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 1)
    ERR!     at async storybookDevServer (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\dev-server.js:103:28)
    ERR!     at async buildDevStandalone (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\build-dev.js:107:31)
    ERR!     at async buildDev (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\build-dev.js:147:5)
    ERR!  SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /%G++%/: Nothing to repeat
    ERR!     at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    ERR!     at H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-common\dist\cjs\utils\template.js:20:24
    ERR!     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    ERR!     at interpolate (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-common\dist\cjs\utils\template.js:19:31)
    ERR!     at getManagerHeadTemplate (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-common\dist\cjs\utils\template.js:63:10)
    ERR!     at _default (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\manager\manager-webpack.config.js:61:99)
    ERR!     at async Object.start (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\manager\builder.js:94:16)
    ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 1)
    ERR!     at async storybookDevServer (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\dev-server.js:103:28)
    ERR!     at async buildDevStandalone (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\build-dev.js:107:31)
    ERR!     at async buildDev (H:\Work\react-storybook\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\cjs\build-dev.js:147:5)
    
    WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
    WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
    
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Running `npx sb info` give the following info.

```
    Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz   
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE       
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 7.17.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 91.0.4472.77
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1023.0), Chromium (91.0.864.48)
  npmPackages:
    @storybook/addon-actions: ^6.2.9 => 6.2.9 
    @storybook/addon-essentials: ^6.2.9 => 6.2.9 
    @storybook/addon-links: ^6.2.9 => 6.2.9 
    @storybook/react: ^6.2.9 => 6.2.9
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] it will be very difficult to help.

Comment: Sounds like it could potentially be the versions mismatch of React or Webpack? To try again, check this https://github.com/dreamworkers/universal-storybook/blob/main/package.json, it used both create-react-app and sb init, with some modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my Windows environment variables were messed up, after a fresh Windows installation everything seems to be working fine.